# relative vs absolute path of a file for php includes

Tags: php, file, include, hierarchy, php-include

So I have this sort of file set up. `/cloud/` and `/embed/` being two different subdomains.

```
www
  -cloud
   --config.php
   --files
     ---formSubmit.php
  -embed
    --index.php
```

in **/embed/index.php** I have the following code:

`include("/www/cloud/files/formSubmit.php");`

in **/cloud/files/formSubmit.php** I have the following code:

`include("../config.php");`

If I am on cloud.website.com and I go to the **formSubmit.php**, everything works fine and the config file is included.

However, If I am on embed.website.com and I go to the **index.php**, I get an error saying that config.php was not found.

Does anyone know what do I need to do to include my formSubmit.php from either location and have my config.php included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it seems your usage of relative paths is working and absolute paths are not. Whether that means the absolute path of `/www/cloud/files/` is incorrect or not, I do not know. In my code, I tend to try to reference files relatively as much as possible like so:

```
// In embed/index.php
include_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/cloud/files/formSubmit.php';
```

What that does is get the directory of the currently executing file and then it's parent directory, which would be `www`, and then goes back down the path from there to the file I need.

Subdomains should not make a difference when accessing files server side (as long as the files are hosted on the *same* server).

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand what you are saying. so `../` works differently than `dirname()` because one is the absolute and one is the working path?

Comment: No. The `../config.php` is accessed as a **relative** path. The `/www/cloud/files/formSubmit.php` is being accessed as an **absolute** path. You mentioned the first is working and the second is not. That absolute path is probably incorrect, as it is typically `/var/www/...`, but regardless, you can access the file with a relative path instead as I indicated above.

Comment: works for me, thanks for taking the time to explain.